# Twitter API, followers that have also allowed app

Tags: ios, twitter

I am wondering if the Twitter API has something similar to Facebook's "installed" user property. In case you don't know what that is, Facebook will return a value based on wether or not a connection has the app installed/authorized (see official description below).

What I am trying to do is show a list of people the user follows who also use the app so they can connect with them. Just like Instagram does with your Facebook friends and Vine does for your Twitter friends.

From Facebook: Specifies whether the user has installed the application associated with the app access token that is used to make the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not possible. At least not any more.

The only way you can do this now is on your end. Which means, storing twitter ID's for authenticated users. Then you can compare the returned friend ids from a twitter GET friends/ids api call to the database you have of stored twitter ids and display those users.

Its a real shame Twitter makes working with their API and data so damn difficult.